# Delete Component after replaceWith() in Tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, memory-leaks, tornadofx

I'm currently learning to use TornadoFx. I'm quite confused with the replaceWith mecanism. The previous view is not released from memory from looking at the heap. I can live with that, because views are singletons, but if I use fragments instead I get a huge memory leak.

Here view1 and view2 are exactly the same, I just go back and forth between the 2, and they stack up in memory.

```kt
class View1 : Fragment("View1") {
    override val root =  vbox{
            button() {
                action {replaceWith<View2>() }
            }
        }
}
```

How can I prevent this ? Where is the reference to these object stored ?

Comment: How do you mesure it? over wich timeframe ? Sadly I can not find the Implementation of "replaceWith"

Comment: I just use Intellij's heap inspector, and I've made it run for more than a minute. The GC should have had the time to do its thing. i.ibb.co/hZ6H5Qt/image.png

Comment: I looked into the code of the function replaceWith(..)
It looks like the root (eg BorderPane ) of the view will be Replaced and removed from the Parent Component (eg Scene). But not the View class. Have you tried to call "removeFromParent()" after "replaceWith()" ?

Comment: Sorry for taking a lot of time to answer. I've tried what you suggested, but It doesn't seem to resolve the issue.